# What if two answers with same content are given at almost the same time?

Tags: discussion, answers, fastest-gun

We, [teshvenk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25640048/jquery-namevariable-as-an-id/25640121#25640121) and I have given the same [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25640048/jquery-namevariable-as-an-id/25640128#25640128) at nearly the same time.

Now, teshvenk has much less rep than me and I'm not hot having rep this way...

**So what to do?**

My first thought was to delete my answer. By the time of writing this, another same answer was given. I'm really unsure what to do in such a case. My goal ist the good of the site, not my rep (anymore ;-)).

**[Update]** It's raining answers on that question.....

Comment: If you feel someone else's answer is better than yours, vote it up. It might even get you close to a nice, shiny Sportsmanship badge, which we have for a reason.

Comment: Did that already on other occasions... Didn't thought of that one, thx!... Done! I think this is my answer.

Comment: i have seen situations when they post some dummy answer just to be first, and then they edit it with correct answer later.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't have to do anything as there's nothing wrong with this scenario.

If you want to delete your answer that's up to you, but perhaps what you should be doing is editing your answer to make it the *best* answer possible. That way you'll get the upvotes.

Comment: As it shows, my answer was the shortest, but by far not the best. Improving would mean copying at least parts of other answers, so I let it be by upvoting the better ones.

Answer (score 4):

Occasionally, two or more answers are given at nearly the same time. That's all fine: If the question is legitimate, and the answers are good, then they will be upvoted, and one answer will eventually be accepted. Maybe the accepted answer will be one that has a few additional words, explaining what was wrong with the original code, or what the proposed code actually *does*.

If you think that the other answer is as good as (or even better than) yours, then you can upvote it, and show some [sportsmanship](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/805/sportsmanship).

(One could start to argue about whether a question that receives 10 answers with the same content within a few minutes can be a "good" question, but at least subjectively, I'd say that this rarely happens for the really *interesting* questions...).

Comment: " I'd say that this rarely happens for the really interesting questions..." Agree with that.